# Is it possible to send google clouds log stream to a local file from command line

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, logging, command-line

Basically, when I run the command `gcloud app logs tail >> logs.txt` I would expect it to store the streamed logs in the output file.

I am guessing that since the command executes asynchronously it ends up storing nothing and stops the process.

If so, is there a way to store the logs without the need of a script?

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing anything because you are redirecting stdout, while gcloud, just like most non-shell programs, prints to stderr. This seems to work fine:

```
gcloud app logs tail >> logs.txt 2>&1
```

In any case except for like some temporary thing (getting logs for a couple of minutes), you should be using sinks for this, not some homebrew solution: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2. Logs will be stored to GCS every hour.